# Next js routing-shallow

Tags: routes, next.js

help me․․․ I use next js, shallow-routing ... this two codes are from two different pages... i want to change the pages without rendering... first is working, but second doesn't working... is there something wrong in pathname...

```
const showFileType = async () => {
        await setFileType(type)

        await router.push({
            pathname: '/all-files',
            query: {
               
                fileType: type
            }
        }, undefined, {shallow: true})
    }


const showAuthorImageType = async () => {
        await setAuthorImageType(type)
        await router.push({
            pathname: `/authors/${router.query.author}`,
            query: {
               
                authorImageType: type
            }
        }, undefined, {shallow: true})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shallow routing only works for same page URL changes. For example, let's assume we have another page called pages/about.js, and you run this:

router.push('/?counter=10', '/about?counter=10', { shallow: true })

Since that's a new page, it'll unload the current page, load the new one and wait for data fetching even though we asked to do shallow routing.